# einsum not giving overflow error when applied to int arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I just had a bug which was based on `np.sum` and an equivalent (or at least I thought so...) `np.einsum` command not giving the same result. Here is an example:

```
import numpy.random
array = np.random.randint(-10000, 10000, size=(4, 100, 200, 600), dtype=np.int16)

sum1 = np.sum(array, axis=(0,1,2))
sum2 = np.einsum('aijt->t', array)

print(np.allclose(sum1, sum2))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(sum1)
plt.plot(sum2)
plt.show()
```

After some searching, this is due to overflow of the integer data type.

My question:

- Why is `np.einsum` not giving the same result as `np.sum` here? I feel the np.sum behaviour is a lot more desirable leading to less errors.
- Why does `np.einsum` not throw an overflow error or at least a warning? This is super scary in terms of getting hidden bugs when using it. Should I be checking for those by hand every time I use the command?
- Would this considered be a bug in numpy?

Comment: `sum` returned a `int32`, while `einsum` left it as `int16`.  Other SO have talked about whether/when `numpy` arrays raise overflow warnings.  I don't recall the details, but in general I don't think they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a large `int16`:

```
In [322]: y=np.int16(32000)
```

Addition produces a warning:

```
In [323]: y+y
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8828\1714217578.py:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in short_scalars
  y+y
Out[323]: -1536
```

`sum` promotes them to a larger int, and no warning:

```
In [324]: np.sum((y,y))
Out[324]: 64000

In [325]: _.dtype
Out[325]: dtype('int32')
```

Make an array from that:

```
In [326]: Y = np.array(y)
```

Overflow without warning:

```
In [327]: Y+Y
Out[327]: -1536
```

I don't recall the details, but it's been explained that checking each element of an array for overflow is/was considered to be too expensive.

Rather than checking 'by hand', just be aware of the overflow possibility, and don't use smaller dtypes unnecessarily.

A possible duplicate

[Sum of positive numbers results in a negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956551/sum-of-positive-numbers-results-in-a-negative-number)

Comment: interesting, thanks! I thought it was a problem with einsum, good to know that this can also happen for simple algebraic operations.